# Transform RxJs Observable of Observables into count of how many Observables are pending?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm making a service that has multiple methods triggering HTTP calls. I want to reveal an Observable to clients that tells them whether there are any pending calls.

I think this approach would generally would work, but feels hacky and not very RxJs-like. I've searched all over StackOverflow and through the RxJs docs, but can't find a better way. Any advice? Thanks!

```
let pendingCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
let pendingCount$ = pendingCountSubject.asObservable();

let pendingSubject = new Subject<Observable<any>>();
pendingSubject.pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    pendingCountSubject.next(pendingCountSubject.value - 1);
  }))
  .subscribe();

function trackPendingObservable(obs) {
  pendingCountSubject.next(pendingCountSubject.value + 1);
  pendingSubject.next(obs);
}

trackPendingObservable(httpCall1);
trackPendingObservable(httpCall2);
trackPendingObservable(httpCall3);
```

And in template:

```
Pending calls: {{ pendingCount$ | async }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, your service has several methods that perform http calls, e.g.

```
httpCall1(): Observable<any> { // do stuff}
httpCall2(): Observable<any> { // do stuff}

httpCallN(): Observable<any> { // do stuff}
```

Somehow these methods run in parallel, maybe because they are called in a rapid synchronous sequence.

What you want to show is how many of them are "on fly" at a certain moment.

Something like this may work.

The service exposes the http call methods as well as a counter of the calls currently "on fly".

```
export class MyHttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)

  public callsOnFly = 0;

  httpGenericCall(httpCall: Observable<any>) {
     this.callsOnFly++;
     return httpCall
         .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.callsOnFly--)
         )
  }

  httpCall1() {
     return this.httpGenericCall(this.http.get('http://my-server1'));
  }

  httpCall12() {
     return this.httpGenericCall(this.http.get('http://my-server2'));
  }

  httpCallN() {
     return this.httpGenericCall(this.http.get('http://my-serverN'));
  }

}
```

The component can just display via interpolation the value of the counter

```
Pending calls: {{ httpService.callsOnFly }}
```

where I assume that the name of `MyHttpService` in the component is `httpService`

Comment: Where does httpService.pendingCount come from? I see no relationship to the code in your class. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right. There was a typo. No ‘pendingCount’ but ‘callsOnFly’. I corrected the code.

Comment: Yes that is the general structure! Sorry I wasn't more clear. I guess I'm looking for a fancy way to next() all the calls into a subject that could to some fancy manipulation to generate all this without having to tally manually. Wouldn't using tap only trigger after the http call returned? And thus not actually show while the requests were pending? (Also I think errors would mean time taps weren't called at all)

Comment: @Rabbit you are right, the `tap` operator to increment the counter is just WRONG for the reasons you mentioned. The counter needs to be incremented before invoking the `httpClient`. I am not sure I understand your point about having a Subject that does something. For sure you can avoid the repetition of the increment / decrement by just isolating it in one method. I have updated my answer accordingly.